# How to fix Dyld Error Message: with Core-Plot MacOSX

Tags: macos, core-plot, xcode5.1

I'm developing an app for MacOSX which runs ok by using XCode5

I recently made .app files from my application for testing and all of them worked good
then I added core-plot for graphics, I added it, developed several graphics and all of them ran without any problem

now I want to make a new .app file for executing it on a testing mac, but when I run it a message appears:

```
Date/Time:       2014-07-29 18:40:32.395 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  B36A335B-8D16-E057-CFD9-EB7A83B099C4

Sleep/Wake UUID: AA7F1A98-6095-4823-BDE3-1E41A97322E1

Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/CorePlot.framework/Versions/A/CorePlot
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/eAccounting.app/Contents/MacOS/eAccounting
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
    0x7fff6f163000 -     0x7fff6f196817  dyld (239.4) <042C4CED-6FB2-3B1C-948B-CAF2EE3B9F7A> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8ad59000 -     0x7fff8ad59fff  com.apple.Carbon (154 - 157) <45A9A40A-78FF-3EA0-8FAB-A4F81052FA55> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff920d4000 -     0x7fff92270ff3  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.8 - 332.3) <72003E51-1287-395B-BCBC-331597D45C5E> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff954d4000 -     0x7fff955befff  libsqlite3.dylib (158) <00269BF9-43BE-39E0-9C85-24585B9923C8> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.68f99...
```

this is the screenshot of the message:

[image]

how to fix this issue for making my app running again with this framework???

thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the build settings in your app. Make sure the Core Plot framework is listed under the "Copy Frameworks" build phase.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was moving an application I made from one computer to another. If you used CMake or something equivalent to generate the project files, then I have a solution: In CMake, instead of selecting XCode as the generator, I switched to Unix Makefiles. Then all I had to do was navigate in terminal to the folder where the make files were generated and type:

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

This created the application with all of the frameworks and dynamic libraries packaged correctly in my /usr/local/bin folder.

I know that this error is also fixable in XCode, but I spent a lot of time fidgeting with the setting without ever figuring it out. This is my solution for packaging the application; however, I still do all of my editing in XCode.

Comment: sounds interesting, could you please tell me where is the folder with all the makefiles??? on my folder project I could not find anything, I guess the folder you're talking about is inside somewhere in /Users/myUser/Library/ am I correct???

Comment: Opps, I forgot about that. For me, in cmake I specify which folder I want to build the binaries and then this is where the makefiles are. For example, I created a new (empty) folder named buildfiles inside of my project folder and then this is where I navigated in terminal to run "make" and "sudo make install"

Answer (score 0):

For fixing my issue that's what I did on XCode5

After adding framework via "Add existing framework"

- My Project Settings -> Build Phases
- In right top corner click on plus button (+) -> New Copy Files Build Phase
- Select Destination -> Frameworks
- Drag & Drop my framework to files list

after that everything worked perfect for me